# Enumerating devices and display modes for OpenGL rendering

Tags: windows, opengl, enumerate

I'm currently writing an OpenGL renderer and am part-way through writing some classes for enumerating display adaptors, devices and modes for use in drop-down lists.

I'm using EnumDisplayDevices to get the adaptors and then EnumDisplaySettings for each device, giving me bpp, width, height and refresh rate.  However I'm not sure how to find out which modes are available full-screen (there doesn't appear to be a flag for it in the DEVMODE structure).  Can I assume all modes listed can in-principle be instantiated full-screen?

As a follow up question, is this approach to device enumeration generally the best way of getting the required information on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL has not this distinction between windowed and fullscreen mode. If you want an OpenGL program to be fullscreen you just set the window to be toplevel, borderless, without decoration, stay on top and maximum size.

Comment: Fullscreen is not the same as a window which fills the entire screen!

Comment: @Dudeson: For OpenGL it is. In Windows and X11 it is. On MacOS X there was a dedicated exclusive full screen access mode, but that's been retired ever since, too.

Comment: @datenwolf: That's very surprising. I mean applications running in fullscreen usually change the desktop resolution. That wouldn't be necessary in a windowed fullscreen mode. Example: http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/window.html#window_full_screen
I might misunderstand though.

Comment: @Dudeson: That resolution change has nothing to do with a dedicated "fullscreen" mode in OpenGL. It's simply switching the display resolution using the same API, that the Windows control panel uses. The reason for switching the resolution in the first place is to reduce the number of pixels to be drawn, if so desired, to increase the framerate. GLFW is open source so I suggest you look at the code responsible.

Comment: @datenwolf: I kinda thought so... I will try looking at the source.

Comment: @datenwolf: I did look at the source now. It does seem to just create a window. But can you tell me why ALT+TAB is such a problem for some applications then? I mean if it's just a window that is filling the screen, why would some applications crash because of that?

Comment: @Dudeson: Those applications for which Alt+Tab is a problem usually don't use OpenGL but (an older version of) Direct3D. Direct3D indeed has an exclusive fullscreen mode, when switching back to the desktop all the graphics resources will be lost and must be reloaded upon return; this housekeeping causes problems for some applications and is the reason, why exclusive graphics access is such a bad idea. OpenGL doesn't do this and games based on OpenGL (which are the minority) usually don't have problems with Alt+Tab.

Comment: @datenwolf: Thank you a lot! That cleared up a lot for me. So does Direct3D still have an exclusive fullscreen mode or has it been deprecated?

Answer (score 1):

The above is actually a dumb question.  By definition windowed mode must be the current display settings.  All other modes must be available full-screen (provided the OS supports them, i.e. 640x480 not advisable in Vista/7).

Answer (score 1):

Hmmph, not correct at all, and with an attitude too. You have variety of functions that can be used.

SetPixelFormat, ChoosePixelFormat, ChangeDisplaySettings.

The PixelFormat functions will let you enumerator available modes. ChangeDisplaySettings with allow you to set whatever screen mode (including bit depth) your app wants. Look them up in MSDN.

Comment: I figure it's ok to have an attitude about your own question :p.

Comment: I didn't notice that was you replying to your own question. I suppose I could forgive the attitude in that case :oP